# How does heat affect the relation between a mother cat and her child?

Tags: cats, behavior

My mommy cat has a 1 year old. She was always a great mother she weaned them perfectly. However one day recently she stopped wanting anything to do with her even as a friend. I was worried I was going to have to re-home one because of the fighting, hissing and generally cruel behavior. I left for 2 days and I came home to a loving mother and daughter relationship again and her full fledged nursing.

My son said it's because they are both in heat. I'm happy they are getting along again but my question is: **Will the mom start wanting her gone once heat is over?**